# How to log python program activity in Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, logging

I'm pretty new to Python programming so I have this question:

How can I log a Python application activity into /var/log with Mac OS X?

I tried using syslog module, but it does not seem to write anything. I tried also with the logging module, but I always run into a permission error.

How can I do it?

Update:

```
import logging
import time
LOG_FILENAME = "/var/log/writeup.log" + time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
LOG_FORMAT = "%(asctime)s - %(filename)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
log = logging.getLogger("main.py")
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch = logging.FileHandler(LOG_FILENAME)
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
format = logging.Formatter(LOG_FORMAT)
ch.setFormatter(format)
log.addHandler(ch)
```

Comment: show how you used those modules.!

Comment: I updated the question with the logging code. I tried syslog only in the python interpreter, using "import syslog" and "syslog.syslog('test')

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I found the solution. It seems that Mac OS X does not record any log activity lower than LOG_ALERT, so this does the trick

```
import syslog
# Define identifier
syslog.openlog("Python")
# Record a message
syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_ALERT, "Example message")
```

This message is recorded on /var/log/system.log

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to use python logging with a syslog handler ?

Comment: Yes, through logging.handlers.SysLogHandler. Take a look: http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html?highlight=logging#logging.handlers.SysLogHandler

Comment: In OS X 10.8, the default is to save everything has higher priority than LOG_INFO in /var/log/system.log.

Comment: Hi, how do exactly parametrize `logging.handlers.SysLogHandler`? I asked for clarification [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72819186/python-logging-to-see-messages-in-console-app-macos), since console can't show human readable messages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command line tool "syslog" on os x, to get all syslog events.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a guide with about 5 steps you need to complete - they're straightforward, and it worked for me:

http://vastdevblog.vast.com/blog/2012/04/18/using-syslogappender-on-os-x/

Pay close attention to this step, as you have to make a few command calls there:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.syslogd.plist

...

Command: Add :Sockets:NetworkListener dict
Command: Add :Sockets:NetworkListener:SockServiceName string "syslog"
Command: Add :Sockets:NetworkListener:SockType string "dgram"
```

Answer (score -2):

the problem is that the account you are running the script as does not have write permission to `/var/log`

I do not know about OS X specifics, but I guess that `syslog.syslog("message")` should print something like (if it acts the way it does in Linux)
`Feb 11 14:27:47 hostname python: message` to `/var/log/messages`

Comment: syslog works fine for GNU/Linux, but Mac OS X does not have a "messages" file like Linux, I tried to find some file where the log events where recorded, but without luck. It has /var/log/system.log but it does not record what syslog sends.

Comment: awfully late response here I know, but on mac /var/log/system.log does indeed record what you send via syslog, it's just filtering low priority messages out by default. try for example: `syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_ERR, "message")`