# Python logging to see messages in Console.app [MacOS]

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, logging

I am trying to see log of my application from macos built-in Console.app. (for comments why: it is convenient for detached programs, has ui, can be filtered, exported and more)

### Problematic Code

```py
import logging
import logging.handlers
import time

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(logging.handlers.SysLogHandler())
logger.setLevel('INFO')

while True:
  logger.info('I am invisible from Console.app :(')
  time.sleep(1)
```

I tried also `address='/var/run/syslog'` and different facilities for `facility=` arguments of `logging.handlers.SysLogHandler`

### Result

And there is an example result from MacOS console application (searched by `any:python` on default device):
[image]

Common message is duplicated over single run:

```
[R86010] DNSServiceQueryRecord(1D000, 0, <mask.hash: 'BPcKH1OFnJhi/+wTtTItxQ=='>, Addr) START PID[8025](Python)
```

### Expectation

Logged messages `I am invisible from Console.app :(` in Console.app every second with its metainfo.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: hopefully this will help please have a look at [here](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/console/cnsl1012/mac)

Comment: @Ameya It doesn't help, because it is a common info on how to use console.app :(
I also tried `log stream --level 'info' | grep python` and there is no any logs from my app

Comment: Try setting the level to `ALERT` rather than `INFO`.

Comment: Is your syslog listening on localhost:514 UDP? From the docs: `Note that if your server is not listening on UDP port 514, SysLogHandler may appear not to work.` https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html

Comment: @MarkSetchell 1)'ALERT' is not applicable, only DEBUG, INFO, ERROR, CRITICAL, WARNING;
2)setLevel specifies lowest level to log, if I do, there won't be any log.

@LMC Do you know how to check if Console.app can listen on it? I also tried `/var/run/syslog` socket and it didn't show

Answer (score 0):

I tried this (SysLogHandler) on Big Sur and I saw log entries only for Python log levels ERROR and WARNING (did not try CRITICAL, but would expect that to slso show up). I used address '/var/run/syslog' which causes Unix domain sockets to be used, and facility LOG_USER.